# Get id of new record in DNN Module

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, linq, dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-module

Am new to DNN Module development and using MVC and Linq. Have built a class and controller that allows me to create a record in a table on the database. Can anyone tell me the best way to retrieve the id of the newly created record? The part of the controller for creating the record is below.

```
class BlockController
{
    public void CreateBlock(Block b)
    {
        using (IDataContext ctx = DataContext.Instance())
        {
            var rep = ctx.GetRepository<Block>();
            rep.Insert(b);
        }
    }
}
```

Call to the controller from the code

```
            var bC = new BlockController();
            var b = new Block()
            {
                SectionId = int.Parse(ddlPickSection.SelectedValue),
                PlanId = int.Parse(ddlPickPlan.SelectedValue),
                BlockName = bId,
                BlockDesc = "",
                xPos = bX,
                yPos = bY,
                width = arrBWidths[i],
                ModuleId = ModuleId,
                CreatedOnDate = DateTime.Now,
                CreatedByUserId = UserId,
                LastModifiedOnDate = DateTime.Now,
                LastModifiedByUserId = UserId,
            };

            bC.CreateBlock(b);
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

When you submit changes (insert the record in DB) the ID would available in b object:

```
...
rep.InsertOnSubmit(b);
ctx.SubmitChanges();

int desireID = b.id;
```